# How can i write a Nusoap client script for asmx web service?

Tags: php, web-services, asmx, nusoap

I need a php client base on nusoap lib. to get a asmx service response with haeder auth enabled:

This is the Request (using soapUI):

`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:res="namespaceurl">
   <soap:Header>
      <res:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:UserName>myuser</res:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:Password>mypass</res:Password>
      </res:AuthHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <res:LoanStatus>
         <res:iAccountNbr>?</res:iAccountNbr>
         <res:iResortNbr>?</res:iResortNbr>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:strXRef></res:strXRef>
      </res:LoanStatus>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Here es the Response (soapUI):`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:res="namespaceurl">
   <soap:Header>
      <res:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:UserName>myuser</res:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:Password>mypass</res:Password>
      </res:AuthHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <res:LoanStatus>
         <res:iAccountNbr>?</res:iAccountNbr>
         <res:iResortNbr>?</res:iResortNbr>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <res:strXRef></res:strXRef>
      </res:LoanStatus>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to use NuSoap (I recommend using the PHP-native Soap extension!), have a look at the client samples in the [Introduction to NuSoap](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapintro.htm):

```
<?php
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('nusoap.php');
// Create the client instance
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost/phphack/helloworld.php');
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'Scott'));
// Display the result
print_r($result);
?>
```

From there it should be straightforward.

Comment: i have the same code with header and evething i need to get resonse HTTP/1.1 200 OK
but i dont see the xml response as an XML. i just get blank. and a pre-formated soap message

Answer (score 0):

You can use nusoap to send raw XML if you are having trouble making a SOAP call to a predefined .NET Web Service.

Check [this post](http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/07/send-raw-xml-with-php-nusoap.html) for more info.

However it is better to try parsing the WSDL file. Try using wsdl2php. It is really nice for parsing WSDL files. It will replicate the data type structure from the WSDL file to a php class library.

You can find a description on how to use it [here](http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/10/simple-soap-client-with-wsdl2php-using.html).